# Steam store scraping - how to get prices from other countries?

Tags: api, web-scraping, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

For a project I want to display data about Steam games, so I'm trying to retrieve data from the Steam store. For apps and packages there is a really nice API to use. (Example: `https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=905370&filters=&cc=US&l=english`)
, but there is no way to get data for bundles. So I have to retrieve each bundle individually from the store (by scraping). (Example: `https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/1232/Resident_Evil_456/`).

I know how to scrape, but the problem is getting data from other locations, means prices from other countries. I tried everything, but I can't get other currencies. There is a "steamCountry" parameter in the cookie header like this: `steamCountry=DE%7Ca430f80515ce15e271873b3b1ed6a207;`, but when I change this parameter to `US` or other countries, just nothing changes. I'm afraid they are using geolocation by IP, but then this parameter wouldn't make sense.

Does anyone know how to retrieve other currencies/countries, besides using proxies from those locations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a website [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/) which has prices for games. They have [bundles](https://steamdb.info/bundles/) page which you can scrape instead of Steam and get the prices for different countries.

Also there is Steam Web API in the footnote which I don't know what it does but it might have some kind of API that can help you fetch the prices of bundles.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, before returning the page with the cost of a product, Steam calls this link "https://store.steampowered.com/dynamicstore/saledata/?cc=US" to Get the cookies for your country. If you manage to call this with the country code changed eg https://store.steampowered.com/dynamicstore/saledata/?cc=FR, i think this might just do it.

Otherwise the solution is to itegrate some code that Programmatically Finds, Connects to, and disconnects from VPNs (here some code I found: https://www.codeguru.com/visual-basic/programmatically-finding-connecting-to-and-disconnecting-from-vpns/)

Happy coding and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. The "salesdata" request unfortunately doesn't help. I now use proxies located in the same country and then I receive the right price.

Answer (score 0):

To view in other currencies, add **?cc=xx** to the end of the Steam Store URL. For example: https://store.steampowered.com/app/1839700/Milk_Bottle_And_Monster_Girl/?cc=DE

This will provide you with the price of the game that Germany pays. In this case, Euros. Always use the country codes to view other currencies.